# PostgreSQL backdating query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to write a query that will return counted records from the time they were created.

The primary key is a particular house which is unique. Another variable is bidder. The house to bidder relationship is 1:1 but there can be multiple records for each bidder (different houses). Another variable is a count (CASE) of results of previous bids that were won.

I want to be able to set the count to return the number of previous bids won at the time each house record was created.

Currently, my query (shown below) logs the overall number of previous bids won regardless of the time the house record was created. Any help would be great!

Example:

```
SELECT h.house_id,
    h.bidder_id,
    h.created_date,
    b.previous_bids_won
FROM house h
LEFT JOIN bid_transactions b
ON h.house_id = b.house_id
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT bidder_id,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN created_date IS NOT NULL AND transaction_kind = 'Successful Bid' THEN 1 END) previous_bids_won
FROM bid_transactions
GROUP BY user_id
) b
ON h.bidder_id = b.bidder_id
ORDER BY h.created_date DESC
```

Example Data:

```
house_id  bidder_id  created_date  previous_bids_won  
1         1          2016-03-21    0  
2         2          2016-02-10    1  
3         2          2016-01-15    1  
4         3          2016-01-01    0
```

Desired Data:

```
house_id bidder_id  created_date  previous_bids_won  
1         1          2016-03-21    0  
2         2          2016-02-10    1  
3         2          2016-01-15    0  
4         3          2016-01-01    0
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ok, hope that helps. The desired effect is with bidder 2. House 3 is the one bidder 2 won but I only want previous wins so that one should be 0 and not 1.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want a cumulative sum:

```
SELECT h.house_id, h.bidder_id, h.created_date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN created_date IS NOT NULL AND transaction_kind = 'Successful Bid'
                THEN 1
                ELSE 0
           END) OVER (PARTITION BY h.bidder_id ORDER BY h.created_date
                     ) as previous_bids_won
FROM house h LEFT JOIN
     bid_transactions b
     ON h.house_id = b.house_id;
```